# Is my Titan X GPU dead?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

PC specs:

- CPU: Core i7 6700k
- mobo: ASUS Maximus VIII Extreme
- GPU: GeForce GTX Titan X 12GB gddr5
- RAM: Corsair 32GB 2133MHz
- PSU: Corsair AX860i
- Cooling: Corsair H100i

Problem:

Whenever I boot, it has no display. Asus q_code is b2 which stuck at boot. Not sure if my PSU can't supply enough to my GPU or my GPU has defects?

Solutions I already tried:

1. Onboard - works via HDMI
2. Clear BIOS and use only 1x8gb stick - did not work if video card installed
3. Use another PSU (but lower watts 550), did not work either
4. Remove CMOS - did not work too
5. Reseat RAM, HDD/SSD, GPU, PSU cables - also didn't work

PS: This PC is just brand new and bought 4-5 months ago. The past issues I had before this is when I got auto-shutdown randomly and sometimes it does not boot and have to reseat the RAM. Sometimes I got boot loop too but never often. I noticed one time I got power surge prompt from mobo on start up boot.

I notice too that GPU light on "GeForce GTX" fades away into no light at all when q_code error b2 prompt.

Comment: Your PSU is more than powerful enough for a Titan X

Comment: Yeah indeed, that's why I'm clueless. If it's GPU, this is my first time to see brand new GPU failing.

Comment: do you have a friend near to your location with a PC that can handle the card? If yes, ask him if you can test the card in his PC. If the card also doesnÄt work there, the GPU is dead

Comment: GPU is dead, went to a comp shop near and have it tested. Same issue so I ended up to RMA. Thanks for all response.